# Difference in HTML output from <c:out escapeXml="false"> and scriptlet

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I am using JSTL to display my data from database in which records also contain some special characters. When I am displaying my record using JSTL as follows:

```
<c:out value="${record.fname}" escapeXml="false" />
```

Then I have to include `escapeXml="false"` in my code so that special characters be shown on my browser window. But when I remove it it just shows me the HTML code for that. But when I am displaying my record using a scriptlet as follows:

```
<%= record.getFname() %>
```

It automatically shows the special characters only instead of displaying the HTML codes for that.

I would like to mention I have already done my job, but just confused a little bit that which one is better.

Answer (score 7):

`c:out` has escapeXml set by default to `true`, one purpose of this is to avoid cross site scripting, such as prevent execution of `script` or any other `html` tags and display them as text instead. So this is an extra feature in JSTL you can say.  If you want to render `c:out` output as normal Html content you have to explicitly set `escapeXml` to false. But `<%= record.getFname() %>` , this is equivalent to plain `out.println`, which does not have this capability to escape Html tags.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but sir when i use <%= %> in the <a> tag i.e when i use url rewriting then at that time when i use this way of passing my value to my other page it gives me only the string before the single quote but when i am getting value using this method from database and displaying it on my web page then it shows the exact string. But when i use jstl tag for passing the vale it does sends exact string

Answer (score 0):

Only set the escapeXML attribute to false when you are accessing internal parameters, not parameters or attributes that are specified on the URL. Pages are susceptible to XSS attack when using unescaped URL parameters.